# nodejs, how to achieve connection pooling

Tags: node.js, connection-pooling

How to implement connection pooling in nodejs, setting http.globalAgent.maxSockets to some larger value only increases concurrent connection, but after all the requests are responded, then the connection gets closed. But I want to retain the connection with nodejs Server to backend server, even after request is processed.

So how I can achieve connection pooling best way in nodeJS?

With regards,

-M-

Comment: Check out [agentkeepalive](https://github.com/TBEDP/agentkeepalive).

Comment: What do you mean when you say retain connection even after request is processed ?

Comment: For connection pooling this answer will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49333388/9506303