# Problem understanding and implementing how promises and asynchronous things work with loops

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, callback

I'm learning node and I have a piece of code that queries data in the db that i'd like to pass into a callback function. But I'd like to only return unique members.

This means that I have to go through the result of the query, and push the unique members into an array, then pass the array into the cb function.

The problem is, the input is also an array that i build the query off. So there's already a loop there.

I've taken a look at some previous SO threads with promises, await, etc. But I'm having some trouble implementing them with loops like in here.

```
static getDestination(envName, cb){
    var ans = new Array();
    var promises;
    DataBase.initDB((db) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < envName.length; i++){
            db.collection('Environment').find({'environmentName' : envName[i]}, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error getting data in getDestination()');
                    return;
                }
                data.toArray((err, content) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('error converting cursor into array');
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        for (const doc of content){
                            if (!ans.includes(doc.destination)){
                                ans.push(doc.destination);
                            }
                            //cb(ans); 
                        }
                    }
                }); 
            });
        }
    })
    cb(ans); 
}
```

Right now, the callback is just a console.log(ans), and it's printing out an empty array [].

If I call the callback in the innermost loop, it returns the proper members, but it gets called as the loop goes like:

```
[]
[ 'DEV' ]
[ 'DEV' ]
[ 'DEV', 'QA' ]
```

I'd like to get only the last line of the output. A thorough explanation would be amazing too!

EDIT: To my understanding, I should be creating an array of promises, and at every iteration of the loop, I should be creating a new promise with the operation as a parameter. Then at the end of everything, I can call

```
Promise.all(promises).then(cb(ans));
```

But I'm having trouble understanding which transaction should I create the promises on. Since if I create the promise in the innermost loop, the cb outside of the loop gets called before the first was even created.

EDIT:

```
exports.initDB = (cb) => {
console.log('Connecting...');
const uri = <mongo connection uri here>;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('eror connecting to db');
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    cb(client.db(process.env.DB_NAME));
});
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: What library are you using? I searched `DataBase.initDB` and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30292578/1541563). Is that the code you're using?

Comment: @jonrsharpe while that's a great generic resource, this question is specific enough to merit its own answer imo. There appears to be no lack of understanding here that the callback is asynchronous, they just need to be shown how to call the callback only under the correct conditions.

Comment: The title mentions promises, but there are no promises in your code. So what do you expect? If it is an explanation, then the Q&A that jonrsharpe refers to is quite extensive on the topic.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's just a utility db class that I wrote to initialize connection to MongoDB in the server. I've edited the post to include that piece of code.

Comment: @trincot I suppose I should've put the stuff that I tried. But they all didn't work like I explained in the first edit above. A little more detail, I tried creating a new promise every time I push into the array.

Comment: You'll want to have a look at [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572). You need to promisify the `db.collection('Environment').find(…)` and `data.toArray(…)` calls. Start small and try writing a helper function that does only that, returning a promise for the `content` when given a `db` and an `environmentName`. Once you have achieved that, we can go calling the helper function in a loop and building a unique array.

Comment: @Bergi I tried to find an elegant way to promisify `find()` and `toArray()`, but the binding makes it kind of awkward. I settled for factoring out the whole callback to `map()` into a separable function, which seems both more useful and less awkward to promisify as a single block.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes, that separate `getDocuments` function looks good. I just don't get why it is a `static` method of something? Also, probably the OP is using mongodb and could just use their native promise support...

Comment: @Bergi I looked in the documentation for mongodb and couldn’t find any references to the functions returning promises. It looked like they just returned cursors. Feel free to correct me, I’d be happy to update my answer and get rid of the constructors completely.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It seems that [mongodb returns promises since version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911838/how-to-use-mongodb-with-promises-in-node-js#comment66869765_37912049), but you are right it is awfully documented. It is in fact in the API docs once you read those of version 2 or 3, but there doesn't seem to be any blogpost about it and all the tutorials and examples still use callback style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Callbacks

Here's how you'd create your array of promises and use it to aggregate `ans` then invoke your `cb()` once. I also suggest using [the Node.js callback convention](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/) of `cb(error, result)` rather than `cb(result)`, since there are multiple steps that can error, and the caller of `getDestination()` should be notified both when the query succeeds or when it fails.

```
static getDestination (envName, cb) {
  DataBase.initDB(db => {
    const envCollection = db.collection('Environment');
    const promises = envName.map(value => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      envCollection.find({ environmentName: value }, (error, data) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);

        data.toArray((error, content) => {
          if (error) reject(error);
          else resolve(content);
        });
      });
    }));

    Promise.all(promises).then(contents => {
      const ans = contents.reduce(
        (ans, content) => content.reduce(
          (ans, doc) => ans.add(doc.destination),
          ans
        ),
        new Set()
      );

      cb(null, [...ans]);
    }).catch(error => {
      cb(error);
    });
  });
}
```

Notice that each [`new Promise()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is constructed synchronously, and `resolve()` or `reject()` is called asynchronously. This is necessary because your database queries do not already return a `Promise`.

If you use an API that does return promises, you should avoid the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1541563) and chain from the existing promises instead.

I also optimized your aggregation of `ans` by using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of an array, so  we can actually omit checking for existing values since a set only keeps one of each unique value unlike an array.

## Promise chains

If you want your `getDestination()` function to return a promise instead of accepting a callback, you can rewrite it like this:

```
static getDestination (envName) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    DataBase.initDB(resolve);
  }).then(db => {
    const envCollection = db.collection('Environment');
    const promises = envName.map(value => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      envCollection.find({ environmentName: value }, (error, data) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);

        data.toArray((error, content) => {
          if (error) reject(error);
          else resolve(content);
        });
      });
    }));

    return Promise.all(promises);
  }).then(contents => {
    const ans = contents.reduce(
      (ans, content) => content.reduce(
        (ans, doc) => ans.add(doc.destination),
        ans
      ),
      new Set()
    );

    return [...ans];
  });
}
```

The key differences are:

- wrap `DataBase.initDB()` in another `Promise` because the result depends on `db`
- return the promise chain from `getDestination()`
- return `[...ans]` from `.then()` instead of passing it to a callback
- remove `.catch()` and let the caller handle any errors

Notice that because we `return Promises.all(promises)` from a `.then()`, we can get `contents` from the outer promise instead of chaining to the inner `Promise.all()`. This is one of the major benefits that promises offer to escape from [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

## Async / Await

Lastly, if you want to use [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) / [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) instead of `.then()`, you can rewrite it once more like this:

```
static async getDestination (envName) {
  const db = await new Promise(resolve => {
    DataBase.initDB(resolve);
  });

  const envCollection = db.collection('Environment');
  const promises = envName.map(value => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    envCollection.find({ environmentName: value }, (error, data) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);

      data.toArray((error, content) => {
        if (error) reject(error);
        else resolve(content);
      });
    });
  }));

  const contents = await Promise.all(promises);
  const ans = contents.reduce(
    (ans, content) => content.reduce(
      (ans, doc) => ans.add(doc.destination),
      ans
    ),
    new Set()
  );

  return [...ans];
}
```

The key difference here is that each

```
return somePromise.then(someVariable => { ... });
```

is replaced by

```
const someVariable = await somePromise;
...
```

## Modularization

P.S. if you want to remove the constructed promises from your `getDestination()` function, you can refactor your code into two helper functions that can be used like this:

```
static getCollection (collectionName) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    DataBase.initDB(resolve);
  }).then(
    db => db.collection(collectionName)
  );
}

static getDocuments (collection, ...args) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    collection.find(...args, (error, data) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);

      data.toArray((error, content) => {
        if (error) reject(error);
        else resolve(content);
      });
    });
  });
}

static async getDestination (envName) {
  const envCollection = await this.getCollection('Environment');
  const promises = envName.map(
    environmentName => this.getDocuments(
      envCollection,
      { environmentName }
    )
  );

  const contents = await Promise.all(promises);
  const ans = contents.reduce(
    (ans, content) => content.reduce(
      (ans, doc) => ans.add(doc.destination),
      ans
    ),
    new Set()
  );

  return [...ans];
}
```

It may be slightly more code than before, but now you have two re-usable functions that can be called from other kinds of queries besides `getDestination()`.

Comment: Thank you for an amazingly detailed explanation.
I'm trying to understand each one right now,
For the cb one, just to make sure I understand what's going on there:
  
1) Go through envName here and create a new promise for each find query
2) The promise resolves with the query result converted into an array
3) If all the promises are resolved
4) Create a set (ans) from the array of resolves (contents)

Comment: So, I just ran it and got: 

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at content.reduce.

ans is a new Set() correct? It's just declared in the outermost reduce().

Comment: @Lavzh I omitted the `{ ... }` from the callbacks of `reduce()` on purpose. If you added them in, you need to `return ...` in the body. At least that's what it seems like you did.

Comment: Thanks so much Patrick, the cb one works perfectly, though i used for loops since I understand it a little better, instead of the reduce. I'm still going through the other solutions, especially the modularized one!