# MongoDB - open and close connection - advise for good practice

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB via its driver for node.js

I typically open a connection (via the `connect()` method) any time I need to perform an operation and close it (via the `close()` method) as soon as I am finished. In my programs, as natural, I need to perform many operations against the MongoDB and therefore it happens that I open and close many times the connection.

I am wondering whether this is a good practice or whether it would be better to open the connection as the first operation is executed, store it in a variable and use the already opened connections for the following operations closing it when the program ends.

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: what framework are you using (node, python, c#)?

Comment: I am using node.js. Thx

Comment: I am using node.js and I am wondering if (and how) the connection pooling would work with the node.js driver. Thx

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656574/how-to-manage-mongodb-connections-in-a-nodejs-webapp

Comment: Also opening and closing a connection on each operation/query creates a pretty horrible overhead when testing, even worse than when using in production.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is best practice to open the connection once, store it in a variable and close it at the end. MongoDB explicitly recommends this. This is the reason why opening and closing a connection is part of the MongoDB API rather than have it happen automatically for each query.

Opening and closing connections for each query will introduce a significant overhead both in terms of performance (CPU + latency), network traffic, memory management (creating and deleting objects), not only for the client but also for the server itself, which also impacts other clients.

About the terminology of *connection*: in some drivers like Java, what is actually created and stored in a variable is not a physical connection, but a `MongoClient` instance. It looks like a connection from an abstract (API) perspective, but it actually encapsulates the actual physical connection(s) and hides complexity from the user.

Creating the `MongoClient` instance only once, for the drivers that support this, will also allow you to benefit from **connection pooling** where the driver maintains active connections in parallel for you, so that you also only need to create one `MongoClient` instance across multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still the last point is not totally clear to me. I am using the node.js driver which I think supports connection pooling. My understanding is that connection pooling allows programs to ask for connections anytime they need, while the driver is responsible of maintaining the pool. If I need to store the connection within my program it seems to me that I am not using the connection pooling concept. Could you pls explain me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Happy to help! Unfortunately, I am not familiar with node.js apart that I heard it's single-threaded. Connection pooling may happen if it still "pipelines" queries in some way. In any case, opening and closing the connection only once should give you a significant performance improvement even in a single thread and even with a single connection. If the API was designed right, it should simply "just work".

Comment: Maybe this should help remove some confusion: what is stored in the variable (at least in Java) is not a connection in itself, it's the `MongoClient` object that encapsulates the entire connection and connection pool machinery.