# Unable to insert data into MongoDB installed on Google Cloud Platform (but it seems like MongoDB is connected)?

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb, google-compute-engine, mean-stack

All I want to do is install MongoDB Community Version on our Debian VM in Google Cloud Platform and insert any element in the database. (Don't want to use the preinstalled packages/ programs for sale on Google Cloud Platform).

I have been stuck on trying just to insert anything into mongodb. I dont know if it I installed something incorrectly or if my code is off (or if Google has restriction). I don't know what the problem is. If someone is kind enough to help out, I would really really appreciate it.

It is really long. Please if you have time, please help...

I followed the MongoDB installation first from:

[Install MongoDB Community Edition - Debian](https://docs.mongodb.com/tutorials/install-mongodb-on-debian/)

[NPM MongoDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)

Here is what I did, from beginning to end.

**1:) Created a VM Debian 8.0 Machine on Google Compute Engine (Installing MongoDB and NodeJS)**

Make Google Cloud Work:

1. Putty Key Generator

   - Generate
   - Move Mouse
   - Key Comment is Username
   - Key Passphrase is Password
   - Save Public & Private Key
2. Google Cloud Add SSH Key

   - SSH Keys
   - Edit
   - Copy Paste Putty Key Code
3. Google Cloud VM Instance

   - VM Instance
   - Create Instance
   - CentOS
   - SSH
   - View gcloud command
   - Run in Cloud Shell
4. Linux Code

   - cd /
   - sudo su
   - sudo apt-get update
   - sudo apt-get install apache2
   - sudo apt install php5
   - cd /var/www/
   - chmod -R 0777 html/
   - cd /etc/
   - chmod -R 0777 apache2/
5. PHPStorm

   - Tools > Deployment > Configuration...
   - STFP host: {IP ADDRESS}
   - Root Path: /var/www/html
   - Username: admin
   - Key Passphrase: password
   - {Remove index.html}
   - {Upload project}
6. Allow .htaccess

   - Run command: a2enmod rewrite
   - Change file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   - Replace in  "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All"
   - service apache2 restart
7. Install NodeJS

   - cd /var/www/html/backend
   - Go to website "https://github.com/nodesource/distributions
   - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash -
   - apt-get install -y nodejs
   - node -v
   - sudo apt-get update
   - sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
   - npm -v
8. Install Packages

   - cd /var/www/html/backend
   - {Have package.json already}
   - npm install express --save
   - npm install cors --save
   - npm install body-parser --save
   - npm install curl --save
   - npm install -g nodemon --save
9. Run NodeJS forever

   - cd /var/www/html/backend
   - npm install -g forever
   - sudo chown root /etc/rc.local
   - sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
   - chmod -R 0777 /etc/rc.local
   - chmod -R 0777 /etc/init.d/rc.local
   - Edit rc.local file
     Before exit 0, add:

     sudo service mongod start

     cd /var/www/html/backend

     forever start -c nodemon server.js
   - Upload file to /etc and /etc/init.d
   - forever start -c nodemon server.js
10. Install MongoDB

    - cd /
    - sudo apt-get install git
    - sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
    - echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian jessie/mongodb-org/3.2 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
    - sudo apt-get update
    - sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
    - sudo service mongod start
    - service mongod status
    - cd /var/www/html/backend
    - npm install mongodb --save
11. Opened Port 8080 and 27017

============================================

**2): The Relevant Code**

So it seems that Mongodb is running and is connected. But when I want to insert data, the connection is disconnected on NodeJS. I dont know why. Here is the important relevant code:

*On click, send data via AJAX to Node JS*

```
function loginAdmin(){
    //Get elements
    const txtEmail = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    const txtPassword = document.getElementById('txtPassword');
    const btnLogin = document.getElementById('btnLogin');

    //When all input in fields are made
    console.log("clicked");
            $.ajax({
                url: ipaddress.concat(':8080'),
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    txtEmail: txtEmail.value,
                    txtPassword: txtPassword.value
                },
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    return false;
                }
            });
    return false;
}
```

*Insert Data to MongoDB*

```
router.post('/', function(request, response) {
    var txtEmail = request.body.txtEmail;
    var txtPassword = request.body.txtPassword;

    mongo.connect("mongodb://"+ ipaddress +":27017/test", function(err, db) {
        db.collection('user-data').insertOne("223");
        txtEmail = "mongodb connecte22";
        response.send(txtEmail);
        response.end();
    });
});
```

**Success that connection with MongoDB:**
[image]
**Error when attempting to insert into MongoDB:**
[image]

Comment: I tried many variations of db.collections insert but keeps disconnecting....

Comment: DON'T CONNECT INSIDE THE REQUEST.  Your server-side connection is intended to be "shared" and "persisted" and not created per request. See [How do I manage MongoDB connections in a Node.js web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10656574/2313887) to understand what you are supposed to be doing.