# What is best way to handle global connection of Mongodb in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node-mongodb-native

I using [Node-Mongo-Native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) and trying to set a global connection variable, but I am confused between two possible solutions. Can you guys help me out with which one would be the good one?
1. Solution ( which is bad because every request will try to create a new connection.)

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;  
var assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = '[connectionString]]';

// start server on port 3000
app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function() {  
  // print a message when the server starts listening
  console.log("server starting");
});

// Use connect method to connect to the server when the page is requested
app.get('/', function(request, response) {  
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    db.listCollections({}).toArray(function(err, collections) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        collections.forEach(function(collection) {
            console.log(collection);
        });
        db.close();
    })
    response.send('Connected - see console for a list of available collections');
  });
});
```

2. Solution ( to connect at app init and assign the connection string to a global variable). but I believe assigning connection string to a global variable is a not a good idea.

   var mongodb;
   var url = '[connectionString]';
   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
       assert.equal(null, err);
       mongodb=db;
       }
   );

I want to create a connection at the app initialization and use throughout the app lifetime.

Can you guys help me out? Thanks.

Comment: you can make one file which will only contain the db connection,then import that connection variable and use that imported variable wherever required

Comment: @UditKumawat Yes I did that but this mongo library for Node has a callback function for the connection I need to use that so again I need to wait for it connect and then start the application I think.

Comment: you can declare a global variable and then use that after initialize to connection variable

Comment: Yes, I thought about it. But, I came across this [Using Global Variables in Node.js](http://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Create a `Connection` singleton module to manage the apps database connection.

MongoClient does not provide a singleton connection pool so you don't want to call `MongoClient.connect()` repeatedly in your app. A singleton class to wrap the mongo client works for most apps I've seen.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

class Connection {

    static async open() {
        if (this.db) return this.db
        this.db = await MongoClient.connect(this.url, this.options)
        return this.db
    }

}

Connection.db = null
Connection.url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test_db'
Connection.options = {
    bufferMaxEntries:   0,
    reconnectTries:     5000,
    useNewUrlParser:    true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}

module.exports = { Connection }
```

Everywhere you `require('./Connection')`, the `Connection.open()` method will be available, as will the `Connection.db` property if it has been initialised.

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const { Connection } = require('../lib/Connection.js')

// This should go in the app/server setup, and waited for.
Connection.open()

router.get('/files', async (req, res) => {
   try {
     const files = await Connection.db.collection('files').find({})
     res.json({ files })
   }
   catch (error) {
     res.status(500).json({ error })
   }
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Yes this is one of the methods to connect but I need to initialize this connection at app initialization and keep it alive for the app lifetime. With above method, you can connect, but you need call **Connection.connectToMongo()** function to connect on each request.

Comment: You only need to call `connect` once in app initialisation, around `server.listen` or `app.listen`. Then the class acts as a singleton, in each place you `require` the connection class, the same (already connected) `database` property is available to use.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. appreciate it.

Comment: I believe the line `if ( this.database ) return Promise.resolve(this.database)` will always resolve to false

Comment: @OsamaSalama yep, fixed

Comment: Connection.db.collection('files').find({})
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null

Comment: @GustavoPiucco I'm getting the same error which you got! Have you resolved this?
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined`

Comment: @Kuppusamy It's likely you haven't called the `connectToMongo` function before trying to access `Connection.db.collection`

Comment: is it possible to tweak this so that the database is not 'hardcoded' in the connection, eg for a local connection `Connection.url` would be `mongodb://localhost:27017`?  so that the database value could be passed through to `Connection` just as the `collection()` value is?

Comment: update: fyi, i had a go at that tweak, it was too long for a comment, so i posted it as an answer, feel free to add the content to your answer if you like, as the logic is all from your answer.  thanks.

Comment: The problem seemed to be that the db function is not being called so instead of Connection.db.collection you need to call the db as Connection.db.db().collection()

Comment: This does not close the connection

Answer (score 4):

Another more straightforward method is to utilise Express's built in feature to share data between routes and modules within your app. There is an object called app.locals. We can attach properties to it and access it from inside our routes. To use it instantiate your mongo connection in your app.js file.

```js
var app = express();

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
.then(client =>{
  const db = client.db('your-db');
  const collection = db.collection('your-collection');
  app.locals.collection = collection;
});
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              // view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

This database connection, or indeed any other data you wish to share around the modules of you can now be accessed within your routes with `req.app.locals` as below without the need for creating and requiring additional modules.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const collection = req.app.locals.collection;
  collection.find({}).toArray()
  .then(response => res.status(200).json(response))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
});
```

This method ensures that you have a database connection open for the duration of your app unless you choose to close it at any time. It's easily accessible with `req.app.locals.your-collection` and doesn't require creation of any additional modules.

Comment: is there anyway you could instantiate mongo connection outside of `app.js`, for example in `config/database.js` (just to keep the file 'cleaner')?  i have tried, but i get stuck thinking about how to access `app` within `config/database.js`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how i did.

```
// custom class
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const credentials = "mongodb://user:pass@mongo"

class MDBConnect {
    static connect (db, collection) {
        return MongoClient.connect(credentials)
            .then( client => {
                return client.db(db).collection(collection);
            })
            .catch( err => { console.log(err)});
    }
    static findOne(db, collection, query) {
        return MDBConnect.connect(db,collection)
            .then(c => {
                return c.findOne(query)
                            .then(result => {
                                return result;
                            });
            })
    }
    // create as many as you want
    //static find(db, collection, query)
    //static insert(db, collection, query)
    // etc etc etc
}
module.exports = MDBConnect;


// in the route file
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId; 
var MDBConnect =  require('../storage/MDBConnect');

// Usages
router.get('/q/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    let sceneId = req.params.id;
    
    // user case 1
    MDBConnect.connect('gameapp','scene')
        .then(c => {
            c.findOne({_id: ObjectId(sceneId)})
                .then(result => {
                    console.log("result: ",result);
                    res.json(result);
                })
        });
    // user case 2, with query
    MDBConnect.findOne('gameapp','scene',{_id: ObjectId(sceneId)})
        .then(result => {
            res.json(result);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**module version ^3.1.8**

Initialize the connection as a promise:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const uri = 'mongodb://...'
const client = new MongoClient(uri)
const connection = client.connect()
```

And then summon the connection whenever you wish you perform an action on the database:

```
app.post('/insert', (req, res) => {
    const connect = connection
    connect.then(() => {
        const doc = { id: 3 }
        const db = client.db('database_name')
        const coll = db.collection('collection_name')
        coll.insertOne(doc, (err, result) => {
            if(err) throw err
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Wont this create a new connection for every request? Idea was to re-use same connection across request/routes @henry-bothin

Answer (score 0):

In Express you can add the mongo connection like this

```
import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
    let mongoClient = null;
    MongoClient.connect(config.mongoURL, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true},function (err, client) {
        if(err) {
          console.log('Mongo connection error');
        } else {
          console.log('Connected to mongo DB');
          mongoClient = client;
        }
    })
let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    req.db = mongoClient.db('customer_support');
    next();
});
```

and later you can access it as req.db

```
router.post('/hello',async (req,res,next)=>{
    let uname = req.body.username;
    let userDetails = await getUserDetails(req.db,uname)
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.data = userDetails;
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research on the answer but couldn't find a solution that would convince me so I developed my own.

```js
const {MongoClient} = require("mongodb");

class DB {
    static database;
    static client;

    static async setUp(url) {
        if(!this.client) {
            await this.setClient(url);
            await this.setConnection();
        }

        return this.database;
    }

    static async setConnection() {
        this.database = this.client.db("default");
    }

    static async setClient(url) {
        console.log("Connecting to database");
        const client = new MongoClient(url);

        await client.connect();

        this.client = client;
    }
}

module.exports = DB;
```

Usage:

```
const DB = require("./Path/to/DB");
(async () => {
  const database = await DB.setUp();
  const users = await database.collection("users").findOne({ email: "" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49400334) that lets you define `database` as well as `collection` when using the connection.  Not sure if it is as 'water tight' as his solution, but it was too long for a comment.

I removed `Connection.options` as they were giving me errors ([perhaps some options are deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958221/mongoparseerror-options-usecreateindex-usefindandmodify-are-not-supported)).

**lib/Connection.js**

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const { connection_string } = require('./environment_variables');

class Connection {
  static async open() {
    if (this.conn) return this.conn;
    this.conn = await MongoClient.connect(connection_string);
    return this.conn;
  }
}

Connection.conn = null;
Connection.url = connection_string;

module.exports = { Connection };
```

**testRoute.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { Connection } = require('../lib/Connection.js');

Connection.open();

router.route('/').get(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const query = { username: 'my name' };
        const collection = Connection.conn.db('users').collection('users');
        const result = await collection.findOne(query);
        res.json({ result: result });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

If you would like to take the middleware out of the route file:

**testRoute.js** becomes:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const test_middleware_01 = require('../middleware/test_middleware_01');

router.route('/').get(test_middleware_01);

module.exports = router;
```

And the middleware is defined in **middleware/test_middleware_01.js**:

```js
const { Connection } = require('../lib/Connection.js');

Connection.open();

const test_middleware_01 = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const query = { username: 'my name' };
        const collection = Connection.conn.db('users').collection('users');
        const result = await collection.findOne(query);
        res.json({ result: result });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error });
    }
};

module.exports = test_middleware_01;
```