# How to use the MongoClient without coding "client.close()" every time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, callback

I try to package the db connecting for more reusable.
I want to achieve like :

```
const mongoPromise =MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true })
.then((client)=>{
      const db = client.db(dbName);

      // do something...

      client.close();
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Thus, I can use it to other places:

```
//For example
//query
mongoPromise.then((db)=>db.collection('user').find().toArray())

//insert
mongoPromise.then((db)=>db.collection('test').insert({...}))
```

When query or insert finished , the MongoClient will be close

At first method,I just can figure out a solution by mixing callback and promise.

**Is it not good for mixing callback and promise together?**

```
// First method
const mongoPromiseCallback =(callback)=>MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(async(client)=>{
      const db = client.db(dbName);
      await callback(db);
      console.log("close the client");
      client.close();
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))

mongoPromiseCallback(db=>db.collection('user').find().toArray())
.then(res=>console.log(res)));
```

At the other method,I try to use only promise,but I don't know 
**where can I close the client**.

```
// the other method
const mongoPromise =MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true })
.then((client)=>{
      const db = client.db(dbName);
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(db);
      });
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err));

mongoPromise.then(db=>db.collection('user').find().toArray())
.then(res=>console.log("res"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always reuse the db object you created in mongo. Here read this it'll answer the question [How do I manage MongoDB connections in a Node.js web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656574/how-do-i-manage-mongodb-connections-in-a-node-js-web-application)

Comment: Oh! Thanks a  lot.I got wrong to use MongoDB. However, I still want to know  how to fix it if it's not in the mongoDB but a common case.

Comment: In that case, one uses connection pool