# MongoDB connection error after 1084 inserts from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and NodeJS.  I wrote a simple app that tests the write speed of a RESTFUL state API:

```
const express = require('express')
const port = process.env.PORT
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/mongo-log', async(req, res) => {
    try {
      let syserr = false;
      let e = null;
      await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL,async function(err,db) {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("-------------CONNECT ERROR----------");
            console.log(err);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        const dbo = db.db(process.env.MONGODB_NAME);
        await dbo.collection("mongolog").insertOne({details:req.body.details,createDate:(new Date())},function(err,res) {

          if(err)
          {
            console.log("-------------INSERT ERROR----------");
            console.log(err);
            process.exit(1);
          }

        });
      });
      if(e) throw e;
      res.status(201).send({"success":true})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }

  })

var cors = require('cors')

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(router)

if(process.env.SSL_KEY && process.env.SSL_CRT) {
    const https = require('https')
    const fs = require('fs')
    const options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_KEY),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_CRT)
    }

    var server = https.createServer(options, app)

    server.listen(port, () => {
      console.log("server starting on port : " + port)
    })
} else {
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
    })
}
```

I start the app with `npm start` from terminal.  Then I wrote a separate python script with an infinite while loop without any sleeper/timeouts that just submits `{details:{a bunch of nested objects}}` with a `request.post()`.

Everything works fine for a few seconds.  But the moment my API has written exactly 1084 records to mongodb, I get the following error from one of my if statements above:

> -------------CONNECT ERROR----------
>
> MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on
>   first connect [Error: write EPIPE
>       at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:150:25)
>       at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:141:3)
>       at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:776:11)
>       at Socket._write (net.js:788:8)
>       at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:453:12)
>       at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:435:5)
>       at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:315:11)
>       at Connection.write (/home/john/projects/dbperformance/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:271:21)
>       at runCommand (/home/john/projects/dbperformance/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:384:8)
>       at performInitialHandshake (/home/john/projects/dbperformance/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:122:3)
>   {   name: 'MongoNetworkError',   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
>   }]
>       at Pool. (/home/john/projects/dbperformance/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
>       at Pool.emit (events.js:210:5)
>       at /home/john/projects/dbperformance/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:561:14
>       at /home/john/projects/dbperformance/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:994:11
>       at callback (/home/john/projects/dbperformance/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:97:5)
>       at /home/john/projects/dbperformance/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:124:7
>       at _callback (/home/john/projects/dbperformance/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:349:5)
>       at Connection.errorHandler (/home/john/projects/dbperformance/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:365:5)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
>       at Connection.emit (events.js:210:5) {   name: 'MongoNetworkError',   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}

Why do I keep getting an error after each 1084 records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't create a new "connection" to MongoDB on every request. Try moving the connection code outside the request handler.

```js
await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL,async function(err,db) {
router.post('/mongo-log', async(req, res) => {
     if(err)
        {
            console.log("-------------CONNECT ERROR----------");
            console.log(err);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        const dbo = db.db(process.env.MONGODB_NAME);

    try {
      let syserr = false;
      let e = null;
        await dbo.collection("mongolog").insertOne({details:req.body.details,createDate:(new Date())},function(err,res) {

          if(err)
          {
            console.log("-------------INSERT ERROR----------");
            console.log(err);
            process.exit(1);
          }

        });
      });
      if(e) throw e;
      res.status(201).send({"success":true})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }

  })
```

Comment: That worked.  It also works if I close the connection after I'm done my queries.  So is it better to keep one database connection alive or is it better to open and close upon each http request?

Comment: @John I think this answer will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10656574/996081