# next.js and mongodb atlas - getting "Connections % of configured limit has gone above 80" alert

Tags: mongodb, next.js, mongodb-atlas

I saw a lot of posts and articles about this alert on MongoDB Atlas ("Connections % of configured limit has gone above 80"), but couldn't figure out how to solve it in my Next.js application.

I create my db connection outside the handler function. I used a middleware `withDatabase.js`:

```
const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URI, { 
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true 
});

const addDbToRequest = (handler, req, res) => {
    req.db = req.connection.db("MYDBNAME");
    return handler(req, res);
};

const withDatabase = handler => async (req, res) => {
    if (!client.isConnected()) {
        await client.connect();
    }
    req.connection = client;
    return addDbToRequest(handler, req, res);
};

export default withDatabase;
```

This middleware wraps the API endpoint handler.

Now, if I close the connection on every API handler when it finishes, like this:

```
    const { connection } = req;
    if (connection) {
        connection.close();
    }
```

Than, I'm getting an error on the second request to the same api handler:

```
MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect
```

And if i'm not closing the connection, i'm getting this alert (after a short time of use) to my email:

```
Connections % of configured limit has gone above 80
```

What is the best practices to work with MongoDB Atlas in a Next.js application?

Thanks!

Comment: hi did you find any working solution? As the accepted answer is not working for my exact same case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The connection should be reused for the following reasons:

1. Opening and closing DB connections on every API request is slow.
2. It's hardly scalable. Assuming you're making a few API requests simultaneously per user, you will reach the same connections limit quickly when the app gets more users.

[How do I manage MongoDB connections in a Node.js web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14464750/5964023)

**2022 update:**

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
const options = {}

let client
let clientPromise

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local')
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect()
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
  clientPromise = client.connect()
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise
```

**Before 2022**

Default `MongoClient` configuration has maximum number of connections per pool (`poolSize`) set to `5`. So, you shouldn't see more than ~5 connections in MongoDB Atlas if you have only one app instance running and checking whether a client is connected already, like you do.

```
if (!client.isConnected()) {
  await client.connect();
}
```

Note, that Next.js "restarts" on every request in the development mode (`next dev`) and it seems it affects `MongoClient` cache and creates many connections. However in production mode, you shouldn't experience this issue.

Comment: so the problem is the develop mode, because i'm not closing the connection..

Comment: what about 'Fast Refresh'? Then in develop mode every code change will trigger new connections which will hit the MongoDB Atlas limit quickly

Comment: Until I learned of the poolSize configuration this did not make any sense. As the MongoDb Guide states `poolSize: Specifies the maximum size of the instance connection pool.` So when you execute `client.connect()` this is setting up a connection 'pool' (which can consist of multiple connections). The developers probably should have worded the `connect` function differently (maybe 'ICP' for instance connection pool) so users are not under the impression that it is simply setting up a single connection to the database. MongoDb Atlas does not seem to track connection pools, only connections.

Comment: Could someone provide an example of how to do this with on NextJS with mongoose?

Comment: @josealvarez97 did you find any working solution? I am desperately looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the max connections reached issue in Next's dev mode, I found writing the reused/cached `client` object to the global Node object allowed it to persist between refreshes.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

async function useMongoClient() {
  if (!this.client) {
    this.client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
  }

  return this.client;
}

module.exports = useMongoClient;
```

Comment: in my env "this" comes up undefined and i cannot attach any params to it... 
"global" is a thing, but i tried to create "global.cachedDB" and it always comes up undefined.