# Nextjs creating more than 1 connections in Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I have this code that connects to the Mongol bank. My old code was creating about 30 connections, now this is creating between 4 and 8 connections. I got this code on mongodb's own youtube channel. Is it normal for him to create these 4-8 connections? I left some console.log to see where the code is passing through, and console.log("bbbbb") is executed only once, but when I look at the mongo it says that it has 4-8 connections.

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

let cached = global.mongo;

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongo = { conn: null, promise: null };
}

export default async function connect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    console.log("aaaaaaaa");
    return cached.conn;
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
  };

  cached.promise = MongoClient.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, opts).then(
    (client) => {
      console.log("bbbbbbbbb");
      return {
        client,
        db: client.db("test"),
      };
    }
  );
}

cached.conn = await cached.promise;

return cached.conn;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Connections to what are you measuring?

Comment: @D.SM the mongodb monitor says they have 8 current connections.

Comment: You haven't answered the question of connections to what.

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61520190/5964023

Comment: @NikolaiKiselev It didn't solve my problem but guided me to other doubts. I will continue researching, if I find the answer I update here.