# Export from MongoClient.connect() is not being read in other module

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node-modules, es6-modules

I'm trying to reuse my MongoClient connection in another module and the export is coming up as null upon import.

index.js

```
import app from './server.js'
import pkg from 'mongodb'
const { MongoClient } = pkg

let db = null

async function listDatabases(client) {
  try {
    const dbList = await client.db().admin().listDatabases()
    console.log('Databases:')
    dbList.databases.forEach((db) => {
    console.log(` - ${db.name}`) // I see the databases here
 })
} catch (error) {
   console.error(error)
 }
}

MongoClient.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  poolSize: 50,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
 .then(async (client) => {
   listDatabases(client) // I see the databases here
   db = client
   app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
  })
 })
.catch((err) => {
  console.error(err.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})

export default db
```

and then in OrdersDAO.js, I'm importing db to be able to access the db and collection. I referred to this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656574/how-do-i-manage-mongodb-connections-in-a-node-js-web-application/14464750#14464750)

```
import db from '../index.js'

static async getOrders() {
   try {
   // db is null here
   console.log('OrdersDAO.getOrders ~~~ made it to the OrdersDAO step 2', db)

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`OrdersDAO ~~~ Unable to get orders: ${e}`)
    return { e }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Below was my original async function and subsequent function call: index.js

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  poolSize: 50,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})

async function connectToMongoDB() {
  try {
    await listDatabases(client)
    app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
   })
 } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Index.js ~~~ Unable to get database.collection: ${e}`)
 } finally {
    console.log('Mongo Connection is closing ~~~~')
    await client.close()
  }
}

connectToMongoDB().catch(console.error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to a database is an asynchronous operation, and as such, it returns a `Promise`. anything assigned inside that function will only be available after that promise resolves. However you are returning the `db` object **outside** the promise, so the js engine does not wait and it is returning the initial value, which is null.
Here is a neat and clean solution I implemented in a recent project, that is also taking into account connection timeout:

**db.js**:

```
const {MongoClient}  = require("mongodb");
const {DATABASE_URL} = require("./config");

async function connect() {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(DATABASE_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  });
   const db =  client.db();
   return { client, db };
 };

module.exports = { connect, dbHelper: connect()}
```

**crud.js**:

```
const { dbHelper, connect } = require("./db");

async function reconnect() {
    return connect();
};

async function getConnectionOrReconnect() {
    let mongo = await Promise.resolve(dbHelper);
    if (!mongo.client.isConnected()) mongo = await reconnect();
    return mongo;
}

//other api functions here
```

Here, I am exporting both the connect function itself and the connection result (as a promise). Than in the other file I'm resolving the imported connection and if it has timed-out I am reconnecting again.

Comment: But with connection pooling, I shouldn't have to reconnect everytime I need the client.?

Comment: That was just an added benefit (I copy-pasted it from my project where I didn't use pooling for some reason). The main point is the way db object is exported as a promise from inside the connect function in the db.js file, and than resolved in the other file.