# TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
at app.post (/home/niko/Desktop/opa/app.js:17:38)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/niko/Desktop/opa/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/niko/Desktop/opa/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/niko/Desktop/opa/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/niko/Desktop/opa/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/niko/Desktop/opa/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/home/niko/Desktop/opa/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/home/niko/Desktop/opa/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (/home/niko/Desktop/opa/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/niko/Desktop/opa/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

Comment: "let db;" ; `db` doesn't point to MongoDB connection. Create connection to MongoDB and use later.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo have created client from mongodb connection. So, you have to use client instead of db like this:

```
app.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const dataJson = req.body;

    try{
        const createdUser = await client.collection("users").insertOne(dataJson);
        res.json(createdUser);
        console.log(createdUser);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.json(err);
    }
});
```

For more information, please visit :
https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/connection/

Answer (score 0):

Out of context, but you shouldn't be posting your Mongo Connection Uri( mongodb+srv://Niko:@cluster0.k8ckw.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority) to public. I tried it and it works. Use dotenv to secure your secrets