# Does MongoDB Node driver create new connection per query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Check the below code:

```js
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

let db;
const options = {};

mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', options, function(err, database) {
  if (err) throw err;
  db = database.db('test');

  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.log(`Express.js server up.`);
  });
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  db.collection('test').countDocuments({}, function(err, count) {
    return res.json({'documentCount': count});
  });
});
```

It is a simple code to do a count operation in MongoDB. My understanding about the above code is that I create a *single* MongoDB connection and assign it to `db`, then reuse it where I need to execute queries.

But [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656574/how-do-i-manage-mongodb-connections-in-a-node-js-web-application#comment131121200_33122516) states:

> Each `.connect()` creates a new connection pool, not a connection

Also, [this article](https://medium.com/@kyle_martin/mongodb-in-production-how-connection-pool-size-can-bottleneck-application-scale-439c6e5a8424) states:

> The pool size is the option that determines how many queries may be run using the same connection in parallel, similar to the number of lanes in a tunnel.

If the `connect()` method is creating a `pool` instead of `connection`, at what point are the connections getting created? Does each `query` create a new connection (or reuse) in the specified pool?

If I execute `.connect()` only once in my code with `poolSize: 5`. Does it create 5 connections immediately?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/connection-pool-overview/

Comment: @jonrsharpe I already referred it. It explains the job of the connection pool. But my question is If I execute `.connect()` with `poolSize: 5`. It will create 5 connections immediately?

Comment: I don't think that's guaranteed. What does it matter? You're telling it to create a maximum of five concurrent connections, but when and whether any given one is  created you're delegating to the pool.

Comment: That's fine. I just worried about the statement I mentioned in the question: `The pool size is the option that determines how many queries may be run using the same connection in parallel`. I know pools manage connections, But can a connection execute queries in parrellel?

Comment: Connect via mongosh and run `db.serverStatus().connections` and monitor while using your applications. Great for understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `mongodb.MongoClient.connect`, you're essentially creating a connection pool, not just a single connection to MongoDB. This pool contains a number of connections that can be reused for different queries, which is an efficient way to handle database interactions in an environment where there might be many concurrent operations happening.

> A connection pool is a cache of open, ready-to-use database connections maintained by the driver. Your application can grab connections from this pool, use them for database operations, and then return them back to the pool once done​. [Source](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/connection-pool-overview/#:%7E:text=A%20connection%20pool%20is%20a,Benefits%20of%20a%20Connection%20Pool)

In your code, when you call `mongodb.MongoClient.connect`, it initializes a connection pool, and the `db` variable holds a reference to this pool. Then, whenever you execute a query like `db.collection('test').countDocuments({}, function(err, count) {...}`, a connection is borrowed from the pool to execute the query, and returned to the pool once the query execution is complete.

Comment: So if I execute `.connect()` with `poolSize: 5`. It will create 5 connections immediately and reuse it. Right?

Comment: Not exactly. The `poolSize` option in MongoDB's Node.js driver sets the maximum number of connections that can be maintained in the pool, but it doesn't initiate all these connections right away when you call `.connect()`. Instead, connections are created on an as-needed basis. When a request is made that requires a database connection and there's no available connection in the pool, a new connection will be created, up to the maximum specified by `poolSize`.

Comment: Alright, But what is the concurrency of query per connection? Can a connection run multiple queries in parallel?

Comment: No, a single connection can't process multiple queries in parallel. It's a one-at-a-time deal per connection. If a query comes in and a connection is busy, it'll have to wait its turn or another connection in the pool will handle it, if available.

Comment: That's what I wanted. Since it is TCP under the hood, I suspected that the `Queries in Parallel` should be false. Thank you so much for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/connect/), the connect() methods connects the **client** you created with `mongodb.MongoClient` to a
MongoDB Atlas deployment, a MongoDB instance, or a replica set the mongoDB driver, and this creates a connection pool.

The number of concurrent connections in the pool is then managed internally by the mongoDB driver, as required by the workload.

However, in the [connection options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/connection-options/) you can override the default settings, including how many concurrent connections there can be for this client (with the `maxPoolSize` and `minPoolSize` options; default value is a 100).

But I think overriding default settings would only be recommended if you are collecting metrics and monitoring MongoDb closely. Then, it may be that you  want to fine tune it with the override settings

Please refer to [THIS](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/number-of-current-connections-to-mongodb/214026/4) very good answer in the mongoDb community forums, for more details.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your clarification.