MongoDB Atlas Global Instance over whole server should be re-usable instead of opening&closing on each request
This is my mongodb.js file where I defined functions to initialize and connection and close it.
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
require('dotenv').config(); // Load environment variables from .env file

let client = null;
let isConnected = false;

const connectToDB = async () => {
    try {
        if (!client || !isConnected) {
            client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_DB_URL);
            await client.connect();
            isConnected = true; // Set the flag to indicate that the client is connected
            console.log('Connected to MongoDB Atlas');
        }
        return client.db('Restomate'); // Replace 'YourDatabaseName' with your actual database name
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB Atlas:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

const closeConnection = async () => {
    try {
        if (client && isConnected) {
            await client.close();
            isConnected = false; // Reset the flag when the client is closed
            console.log('Connection to MongoDB Atlas closed');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error closing MongoDB connection:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

module.exports = { connectToDB, closeConnection };


And for example I do have my controller.js where I imported the re-usable functions to close and open same time.
 let db;
        try {
            db = await connectToDB();
            const ordersCollection = db.collection('Orders');

            const id = new ObjectId(req.params.id);
            const orderStatus = parseInt(req.params.orderStatus);

            const order = await ordersCollection.findOne({ _id: id });

            if (!order) {
                return res.status(404).json({ message: "Order not found" });
            }

            const result = await ordersCollection.updateOne(
                { _id: id },
                { $set: { orderStatus} }
            );
            const updatedOrder = await ordersCollection.findOne({ _id: id });

            if (result.modifiedCount === 1 || updatedOrder.orderStatus===orderStatus) {
                res.status(200).json({ message: "Order status successfully updated" });
            } else {
                
                res.status(500).json({ message: "Error occurred while updating the order status" });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error", error: error.message });
        }finally{
            if(db) closeConnection()
        }

Main problem is: I don't want to reach above 80 connections on my free mongodb atlas cluster tier. I just want to make one re-usable connection instance.
I also would like to know what is the pooling option that I do pass as a parameter in the mongodb url  and does it help reduce the connections.
I don't want to reach 80 connections with opening&closing.

This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62169792/2282634

Does this answer your question? How do I manage MongoDB connections in a Node.js web application?

I used the method of app.locals.db = db to make it only 1 instance re-usable; still my mongodb atlas DB reaches 402 connections instantly for no reason. Can anyone help? If yes I'll share my code with you( the updated one)
